# VB.Net Mimic Start - Run Command

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to mimic the Start - Run box in VB.net?

Specifically, I'm trying to mimic pressing Win+R, typing "notepad++ "C:\Users\Steven\Documents\config.cfg" and hitting return.

Is this possible?

I've tried using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad++ ""C:\Users\Steven\Documents\config.cfg""")
```

and

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad++ C:\Users\Steven\Documents\config.cfg")
```

and I get an error saying "The system cannot find the file specified" for both of them.

I've tried using

```
Shell("notepad++ ""C:\Users\Steven\Documents\config.cfg""")
```

and

```
Shell("notepad++ C:\Users\Steven\Documents\config.cfg")
```

and I get an error saying "File not found" for both of them.

When I type notepad++ "C:\Users\Steven\Documents\config.cfg" in the run box and press return, it opens without a problem.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Process.Start` overload you're using expects you to pass a filename, and cannot find a file named "notepad++ C:\Users\Steven\Documents\config.cfg". You need to look at the [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overloads to find one that allows you to pass arguments, such as [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So try:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad++", "C:\Users\Steven\Documents\config.cfg")
```